# setting a redis cluster on ubuntu using jedis

Tags: redis, jedis

Im trying to set a **Redis cluster** (3 masters, 3 slaves) using **JedisCluster**. How should I set up the configuration files for the nodes of the cluster? 
Does JedisCluster methods are sufficient to set up the cluster?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JedisCluster` is to communicate with Redis cluster.

First, you have to set up Redis cluster on your own. There are several resources (tutorials, blogs, etc.) are available online. Google for those. To begin, you can take a look into [Redis cluster tutorial](https://redis.io/topics/cluster-tutorial).

After setting up, you can communicate with that Redis cluster by `JedisCluster` (as well as many other ways).